# Task stops updating mouse when hovering over title bar

Tags: c#, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, mouse

I have a simple windows forms app to display my mouse location it has 2 text boxes and a button that's all.  See the code below.  It works fine until I hover over the app's title bar but not the whole title bar.  It just seems to be a spot between the text and the icon when moving horizontally.  It's harder to make it happen when moving the mouse vertically.  The app stops reporting the mouse position is non-responsive.  Can someone help clue me in as to why and how to fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MouseTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }
        private bool Run;
        private SynchronizationContext _SyncContext;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run = !Run;
            if (Run)
            {
                DisplayMouseLocation();
            }
        }

        private void DisplayMouseLocation()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (Run)
                {
                    SendOrPostCallback callback = arg =>
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = MousePosition.X.ToString();
                        textBox2.Text = MousePosition.Y.ToString();
                    };
                    _SyncContext.Send(callback, null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the x,y from event?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: Did you debug your task? What's the error? MousePosition works properly?

Comment: There's no error it just stops responding.  Unless you know a way of getting an error from that?

Comment: Task.Error. You need to store the refernce for your task

Comment: ok but how do I get that error if the app isn't responding?

Comment: In debug. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141839/discussion-between-lornecash-and-vmatm).

Comment: @LorneCash I've ran your code as-is and it works as expected. You can try to `await` the `Task.Run` to see any exception. Or can you post anything that can help repro the problem?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem again and it's much harder today and after freezing for a few seconds or comes out on this own... Is it possible that its not getting a high enough priority on the system or something and that the problem isn't necessarily the coffee itself?

Comment: The code posted is not going to freeze, it sounds as though your other code may be the root of the issue. If you can isolate the code that is causing problems you can post that or open a new question relevant to that code. The problem definitely isn't the coffee though :)

Comment: There is no "other code" this is my entire project and it definitely does not run smoothly... I mean it does for a while then it gets glitchy and sometimes freezes.